# Where to put XML file in CakePHP?

Tags: xml, cakephp

I am total dummy to programming, php, and cakephp altogether so pls be patient with me. I created an xml file and I don't know where to place that in my cakephp app. Pls advice...

Comment: Wherever you want. What's it for?

Comment: I just wanna know if there is a specified folder for that. Im thinking if I placed that in a wrong folder maybe I won't be able to parse it.

Comment: No, Cake doesn't eat XML files. Still, what's it for? Is it a config file? A data store? Something a user is supposed to download?

Comment: Data storage. I want to put some data there.

Comment: Are there any differences if its config, data store, or user upload? Can you pls tell me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Data storage. I want to put some data there.

Then I'd put the file in `app/models/data/` or possibly `app/data/`, if it's static data. Yes, these folders don't exist, just create them. Then again, there're probably better ways to store static data than XML files which need to be parsed every time.

Comment: if its in app folder it means that I should put that in the core cakephp?

Comment: No, don't ever touch the `/cake` folder (unless you're working on the Cake core). Put it in any folder that makes sense in the `/app` directory.

Comment: Ok I got it... I think I'll put that in the model.